# CORS issues with local web development and remote API

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, web

We have a Node.js Express web server running on localhost and an API running remotely. For our backend devs we run both projects locally, but for our front-end devs it's much more convenient to just run the web server locally and the API remote. But we run into CORS issues specifically when trying to authenticate cross-origin (from localhost web server to remote API) using cookies - is there a standard setup to avoid this? The only way I know of doing this is to use a session store in a database instead of using cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this header in your res object before router middleware.

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   next();
});
```

Comment: we got that, thanks, still doesn't seem to work, it's something to do with passport